# Sorting primeng table's visible column with a hidden ranked column

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a requirement to display a large number in a particular column and hence displaying in string format. But when I sort the column, it is sorting based on string value and I want it to have it based on numeric sort.

To achieve this, I had introduced a hidden column with ranking value. I had marked this rank column as the p-sortIcon's sort field and displayed the original value column as depicted in the attached image.

RemainingValue = Column containing the displayed value in UI
RemRankValue = Column containing the ranked value for the row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the approach to have the header row to be static and pSortableColumn set to the ranking column for the value to be displayed column. All other approaches did not work for me.